# Post action not working in controller but working in another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project that allows users to create a new project. The UI has some textboxes and a submit button. It sends data through a POST request to an api call, which then creates a new project entity in the database. I deleted my migrations and then added a new migration since I wanted to fix some code, but now the post action no longer works. I see the following error message in the console -

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate
> 'IssueTracker.Controllers.ProjectController'.

**Create new project**

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Projects project)
{
    _repository.CreateProject(project);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Projects Model**

```
public class Projects
{
    public Projects(string name, string description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Projects()
    {
        //
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string description { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What are the values you receive for name and description property on your Api-end?

Comment: @atiyar So I just looked at the error in the console and it says ```System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate 'IssueTracker.Controllers.ProjectController'.``` When I removed the automapper code it posts to the db successfully. Its weird though since I'm pretty sure I installed automapper but I guess its not recognizing it.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error message indicates you have `AutoMapper` installed but it is not being registered/resolved by the dependency injector.

Install the package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` and add the following line in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs file -

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

This will do if the `Startup` class and your mapping profile class/classes are in the same assembly/project. If they are not, then use the following -

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MyMappingProfileClass));
```

where `MyMappingProfileClass` is the mapping profile class where you have defined/configured your maps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Newton.Json nuget package, then pass a ViewModel back to controller without [FromBody]. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Just tried it, still no luck. Why would you suggest taking [FromBody] out though?